# iTunes: app version 2.1 and uploaded build version 3.0 (1.0)

Tags: ios, deployment, itunes

1. The last version was 2.0 and i uploaded new build with versiov 3.0
   and build1.0 3.0(1.0) to iTunes.
2. The app info i.e app version was changed by client from 3.0 t0 2.1
   and the updated info got saved successfully.
3. **So will apple accept or reject submitted app with app version named
   2.1 and build version 3.0(1.0)**.

Comment: The build was rejected for other reason but not due to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO but is not recommended.